# Removing all part of my file except data in []

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a file like

```
"17846753: (3957,-3519,4165)  [19,9,-68,17] 17293388: (3957,-3690,4138)  [19,9,-68,18] 1672052: (3957,-3861,41112)  [19,9,-68,19] 193083: (3900,-2655,4165)  [19,9,-67,12]";
```

I want to remove all things except data in `[]` at the entire file, I wrote a program that works for one bracket, but I can't extend it globally.
This is my program for the file containing one bracket
`~ s/.*\)\s*//;`

Comment: Post some code, show us what you get, and what your expected output is

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Try this example code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = "17846753: (3957,-3519,4165)  [19,9,-68,17] 17293388: (3957,-3690,4138)  [19,9,-68,18] 1672052: (3957,-3861,41112)  [19,9,-68,19] 193083: (3900,-2655,4165)  [19,9,-67,12]";
my $result = "";

while( $data =~/(\[[^\]]*\])/g ) {
    $result .= $1;
}

print $result, "\n";
#<-- prints: [19,9,-68,17][19,9,-68,18][19,9,-68,19][19,9,-67,12]
```

As you can see, I am using a `regexpr` and `while` together with the `g` modifier to iterate over all matches (adding to `$result` the `$1` match).

Comment: Although you don't say it (outside of code), you've done the clever trick of turning the problem on its head so you're keeping the parts you want instead of deleting the parts you don't. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer*: you may very well use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
\[[^][]+\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^][]+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/AgOVno/1).

---

*Longer answer*: you'll often encounter the problem to get rid of something in strings or to keep things of interested. Sometimes it's easier to delete all that's not necessary, sometimes it might be easier to just extract what you need.

With this particular solution you say roughly the following:

```
match this or that (let the engine ignore everything to the left)
OR match something of interest
```

In terms of regular expressions (PCRE and the like), this can be translated to:

```
\[[^][]+\]     # match "[" literally, anything not "[" nor "]" and "]" literally
               # that is everything between "[" and "]" (except nested brackets)
(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # "forget/ignore" anything matched thus far
|              # or
[^][]+         # match anything not a "[" or "]"
```

So what you really say with this pattern: match everything between `[` and `]`, forget about it and match everything outside `[` and `]`, effectively highlighting everything outside the brackets.
This can then be deleted.

Folks argue that this is a complicated pattern and one could agree in a way. Nonetheless, I provided it to have an alternative solution and to show what else might be possible.

Comment: That's some pretty complicated stuff for the problem, and whoever has to maintain it will probably just get rid of it. Instead of deleting the parts you don't want, this is harder, keep the parts you do want.

Comment: @briandfoy: While possibly true, the expression itself is not hard to grasp once you understood the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` thingy. I leave the answer here for the OP to decide and to provide alternative solutions.

Comment: It does answer the question :-) ++

Comment: @Jan Then perhaps you should explain the "`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` thingy".

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Thanks.

Comment: @briandfoy: Added some explanation.